# Use active record in ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a ruby gem which can generate some code in other language. The gem needs to load the models in the current rails app. And it's implemented as a generator which accepts one parameter -- the table name. Inside it, read the columns definition from that table in this way:

```
tableklass = table_name.to_s.constantize  # get the class name from table_name
cols = tableklazz.columns  # get columns definitions.
```

When I run the generator 'rails g mygen Product'. It always gave me the error below:

> .../ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get': wrong constant name products (NameError)

How can I fix this error? Or whether is there other better way to do so (read table information to generate some code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`constantize` expects](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) camelized input. I am not sure, what is happening inside your generator, but it looks like `constantize` finally receives `products` as a parameter. Safest version of what you are trying to do:

```
table_name.to_s.singularize.camelize.constantize
```

Everything below would work:

```
:products.to_s.singularize.camelize.constantize
:product.to_s.singularize.camelize.constantize
'product'.to_s.singularize.camelize.constantize
Product.to_s.singularize.camelize.constantize
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! This is my first gem, you saved a great gem! :-)